# How to not allow specific item get deleted on DynamoDB?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In our DynamoDB database, we have table where we usually have thousands of items that are junk because of test_data and we clean it up once awhile.
But there is a specific item that we don't want to delete but when we do select all, that one gets deleted as well.

Is there a way in the table, where we define the ID and stop it from getting deleted? Or if someone comes and wants to delete all, it will delete everything except that one?

Comment: I would recommend rethinking the whole thing so you don't have to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two options:

1. Add a policy, to anyone (or any role) who might perform this action, that denies permission to delete that item. You can accomplish this by [Specifying Conditions: Using Condition Keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html#FGAC_DDB.ConditionKeys) using the `dynamodb:LeadingKeys` condition key.
2. Add a stream handler to your table and any time the record is deleted you can automatically add it back.

The first option is probably best, but you would need to be sure it's always attached to the appropriate users/roles. You also need to be sure you are handling the error you're going to get when you try to delete the record you aren't allowed to delete.

The second option removes the need to worry about it but it comes with the overhead of a Lambda running everytime you create, update, or delete a record in the table (with some batching, so not EVERY change). It also opens up a brief period where the record will be deleted, so if it's important that the record NEVER be deleted then this isn't a viable option.